# Plotting multiple lines grouped by one column dataframe, with date time as x axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

My data looks like the following:

```
Date,values,ids
2018-10-02,0.9907,1
2018-10-11,3.3784,1
2018-10-11,2.9163,1
2018-10-18,3.7815,1
2018-10-18,0.0874,1
2018-10-08,12.9632,2
2018-10-08,10.4358,2
2018-10-14,9.0246,2
2018-10-14,50.8519,2
2018-10-21,6.9922,2
2018-10-21,5.8701,2
```

Here I want to plot the `values` as a line with respect to time, each line correspond to the values of one `id`. Below is my attempt and the image it generated.

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.txt')
data['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data.groupby('ids').plot(kind='kde', x='Date', y='values', ax=ax)
```

[image: image generated]

I think the reason the x axis doesn't look right is that the `Date` values for the two groups don't match. Is there a way to put these two groups into the same scale as xticks? For example: 2018-10-02 to 2018-10-21 with 1-day increment.

Comment: Your best bet is to probably create a new column to use as your x-value.

Comment: Can you please post your dataframe as Python code? That makes it quicker to reprodruce your problem.